# making a difference in X and a atom

Tags: prolog

I'm searching for a solution to this.
A user can use `my_predicate(X)` or `my_predicate(item)`.

I want to achieve that both gives different output.
so I have to check if it's a `X` or a `item`.

I know that item can be checked by this: `atom(item)` 
But how can I check on the `X` .

Roelof

Edit 1. 
Weird, 
On the SWI-Prolog site they say this wont work.

```
my_predicate(X) :- 
   var(X) ,
   write("here a name is typed in").

my_predicate(X) :- 
   nonvar(X) ,
   write("here the X is typed in").
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to the page on SWI's site that discusses the problem?

Answer (score 1):

var/1 it's the simplest metaprogramming tool available in Prolog, since it allows to change program behaviour depending on such fundamental property as the instantiation of a clause' variable.

I sometime use this construct

```
some_applicative_code(X) :-
  ( nonvar(X) ; X = some_default_value ),
  ...
```

to have a kind of default value for arguments, usually for testing purpose.

Calling `?- some_applicative_code(_).` X will bind to `some_default_value`.

From your edited post, seems you are inverting the logic. I would expect

```
my_predicate(X) :- nonvar(X) , write("here a name is typed in").
my_predicate(X) :- var(X) , write("here the X is typed in").
```

*edit* here is a test

```
1 ?- my_predicate(_).
here the X is typed in
true.

 2 ?- my_predicate(carlo).
here a name is typed in
true .
```

Comment: The swi-prolog people say on thier mailinglist that my idea wont work. I need to use atom(x).

Comment: @user3426797: yes, if you want to be sure it's an atom... Maybe I don't understand the question...

Comment: The question is stil the same. I want if a user enters my_predicate(X) then another text must be displayed then if a user enters my_predicate(item).